# Jest: Imported class 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Importing class Grid into test file but keep on getting errors that its undefined.

The import path is correct but I keep on getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'grid' of undefined" and "Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined" in the console when I run Jest.

Grid.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Grid from '../../components/Grid';

let grid;

describe('Grid', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        grid = shallow(<Grid/>);
    });

    it('renders correctly', () => {
        expect(grid).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    describe('splitUpTiles', () => {

        it('returns an empty array if a.length === 0', () => {
            expect(grid.instance().splitUpTiles([0,1], 0)).toEqual([]);
        });
    });

});
```

Grid.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Tile from './Tile';

class Grid extends Component {

splitUpTiles = (a, l) => {
    if (a.length === 0) return [];
    else return [a.slice(0, l)].concat(this.splitUpTiles(a.slice(l), l));
};

(omitted code for brevity) 

        render() {

(omitted code for brevity)

        return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                {this.createColumns(arrayOfTiles)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
     )
   }
 }

export default Grid;
```

I tested my other files in the same way but had no error. Can someone please explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a **scope issue** with **beforeEach**.

According to the docs:

"By default, the before and after blocks apply to every test in a file. You can also group tests together using a describe block. When they are inside a describe block, the **before and after blocks only apply to the tests within that describe block**".

Try this:

```
describe('Grid', () => {

    let grid; // Move your var inside describe

    beforeEach(() => {
        grid = shallow(<Grid/>);
    });

    it('renders correctly', () => {
        expect(grid).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
    // Delete second describe block
    it('returns an empty array if a.length === 0', () => {
            expect(grid.instance().splitUpTiles([0,1], 0)).toEqual([]);
    });

});
```

Check docs [HERE](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown)

Comment: hey, I've tried this and I receive the same error. I even took the grid = shallow(<Grid/>); outside of the beforeEach block and it still considers grid as undefined. I don't think moving the let to inside of the describe block makes any difference and I don't think my issue is to do with the beforeEach block. Somehow the grid component is not being imported properly

Comment: I have no error importing Grid (not underlined by IDE and no console error), its the correct path and the file is in the correct place. But the error must be something to do with it, I just don't know what. I've tested the other components in the same way and none of those components have been undefined.

Comment: If you think it's useful, share it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. My issue was in some of the code I omitted from what I submitted on here. I thought it wasnt related but it was. I had "const grid = this.props.state.grid;" in the render part of the Grid class. I never passed props to the import when shallow rendering it in Jest so it was saying it was undefined. In terms of useful, its not really. Just me being an idiot haha

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of nested describe. Can you try putting your inner `it` inside above `describe` like below.

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Grid from '../../components/Grid';

describe('Grid', () => {

    let grid;

    beforeEach(() => {
        grid = shallow(<Grid/>);
    });

    it('renders correctly', () => {
        expect(grid).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('returns an empty array if a.length === 0', () => {
         expect(grid.instance().splitUpTiles([0,1], 0)).toEqual([]);
     });

});
```

Comment: hey, just tried this and I receive the same error :/

Comment: can you try now. i edited the answer above. If it still does't works you need to debug if beforeEach is called before each test case.

Comment: unfortunately I have the same error. Even if I remove the beforeEach block and define grid normally I get the same error.

Comment: @SlimJim - if you've found a solution, please share it here. Others (like me) may find it useful.